# UX Builder not loading on Flatsome Child theme

Tags: wordpress, themes, loading

I can't access the UX Builder- it's coming up in a stuck 'loading' pattern.
Here's a screen shot:
[(screenshot of issue I'm encountering)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kiRo.png)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated-
thanks!

M

I haven't tried anything other than going to the Appearance menu a few times, and otherwise have simply looked at various forums but they're all older, plus i'm not comfortable doing javascript or other coding, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue as you. I'd read somewhere that it has to do with SSL. Installed the Really Simple SLL plugin and went through the prompts to set it up, and guess what...it fixed the issue!!!:)

Hope this helps!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).